# Reverse-Engineering Trader Joe's Garden Vegetable Soup

Tags: vegetables, soup, recipe-reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse-engineer Trader Joe's garden vegetable soup. I have the full ingredients list and the nutrition facts. However, I don't know what ratios to use (the recipe itself is very simple) for a 12-cup batch.

I'm guessing that reverse-engineering this soup formula is going to take some trial and error, but I'd like to make this as efficient as possible. Any suggestions?

Here is the ingredients list:

VEGETABLE BROTH (WATER, VEGETABLE BROTH CONCENTRATE [MIREPOIX {CARROT, CELERY, ONION}, SALT, ONION POWDER]), DICED TOMATOES IN JUICE (TOMATO, TOMATO JUICE, CITRIC ACID [ACIDIFIER], CALCIUM CHLORIDE), SWEET POTATO, CARROT, ONION, CELERY, TOMATO CONCENTRATE, MIXED GREENS (KALE, SWISS CHARD, SPINACH), POTATO, TOMATO PASTE, ZUCCHINI, RED BELL PEPPERS (RED BELL PEPPERS, WATER, SALT, CITRIC ACID [ACIDIFIER], CALCIUM CHLORIDE), LEEKS, EXTRA VIRGIN OLIVE OIL, SEA SALT, GARLIC, SPICES (BLACK PEPPER, THYME, RED PEPPER), CITRIC ACID (ACIDIFIER).

The ingredients are supposed to be listed from (largest amount used) to (least amount used)

The nutrition facts per cup are linked [here](https://www.traderjoes.com/home/products/pdp/068420)

I know that based on the amount of fat per cup (2g), 4 tsp oil would be used per 12-cup batch.

Comment: The trouble with trying to reverse engineer something like a commercial soup is you can’t put it through the same heat process. A friend of mine won a competition to have her soup made commercially & they never did manage to match it from her original recipe. The manufacturer was one you would qualify as a ‘fresh’ soup, refrigerated carton not can. (Covent Garden for those from the UK)

Comment: How does the commercial heat process change the flavor?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but apparently it does.

Comment: Also there are very subtle differences such as water quality, PH etc. that may affect the outcome e.g. Scotch whisky etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would sweat one of each of the vegetables (chopped) in 4tsp oil, beginning with the onion, leek, carrot, celery, and 2 sliced garlic cloves.  Then add a TBS of tomato paste. Add zucchini and sweet potato, one each, chopped, Cook for a minute or two.  Add 1/4 tsp black pepper and red pepper.  Add 1/2 tsp thyme.  Toss in one roasted red pepper, chopped, along with a 14 oz can  of chopped tomato.  Add 12 cups veg. broth and bring to a simmer.  Toss in a couple of cups of chopped mixed greens.  Cook until potato is done. Salt to taste.

Comment: wont the pepper and zucchini be mush by the time potato is done?